# Cant change or recover password

Tags: kde4

**TL; DR**: Went to change password after suspecting my system got compromised, and realized i can't see any users under "User Accounts" and can't change password in terminal with `passwd` ; how do I fix this ?

After getting kernel panic while on an umprotected network ( public library,  that is ) I've realized that the laptopt login screen hangs forever. Once I went to change password I've realized no user  ( i have two ) shows up in users and group menus of any desktop environment.

I've successfully changed root password with passwd , but passwd for myself asks for kerberos password ( which is apparently a kde thing ). I currently type on phone , so can't post any screen shots.

Now, I do have ftp and telnet on my laptop enabled so I wouldn't be surprised that my system got compromised.

Any suggestions besides reinstalling the system or nuking it from yhe orbit ? Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: kerberos is a network authentication protocol, so maybe is this a business laptop your IT department configured authenticate to the corporate network?  If so, you will need to have them reset your password.

Comment: It's a personal laptop.  I've installed kde and heimdall , and as far as I understand,  kerberos comes with either one of them. So you can guess that I've no idea how to deal with kerberos. Right now I'm removing kde completely and have already removed the two user accounts I had , and have created new sudoer profile

Comment: I think I may have over reacted a little bit

Comment: Well I have removed kde and reinstalled ubuntu desktop but still same story. Type passwd , it asks Current Kerberos Password. I enter my ubuntu password , it asks question one more time and gives  Authentication token manipulation error

Comment: Serg, have a look at [what's a good backup strategy for 1 PC]( http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc). You're user type 4.

Comment: I think I've clearly stated what I'm asking before in TL:DR part at the top, but just in case, I edited it again.

Comment: @Fabby Thanks ! My lappie is definitely my life, and I haven't done any backups, unfortunately. Good material for the future though !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What has happened**

- After I've got kernel panic and my lappie crashed on a public wifi, I went to reset password, and realized kerberos would not let me, though the password I entered 100% was correct
- I could not see any users appearing in any graphical app from any desktop environment that allows managing user accounts
- checking with `netstat -tpn` I noticed an established tcp connection from ssmtp  to a chinese ip address

**What caused the events**

- Last years' spring, when I just started out with Ubuntu, I've commented out  line `Exec=/usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon`
  form file `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.Accounts.service`. The idea came from a [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2145637.html) about changing greeter background.
- I knew of the effect before, but since then forgot what happens.
- apparently disabling this daemon somehow "confused" kerberos
- kerberos itself may have come with kde or from mistakenly installing heimdal instead of heimdall (a program for android), but these are more of a guess than facts
- I've been using newer 3.18 kernel, as well as new wireless card (rtl8192se). Wireless card has been giving much trouble to me: frequent drops of connection and interfering with audio in any playback (youtube, smplayer, etc.), which does not occur with the original card.
- the "chinese-connection" came from long ago , when I experimented with ssmtp before discovering how I can use msmtp with mutt to check my email, which is . . . .chinese.

**What I've done to fix the problem**

Mainly what has done the job was removing kde and other several packages, among which were heimdal. There may have been other packages, but i didn't exactly document the process well.

Basically, in the last 24 hours, I've bricked the system over and over by removing kde, heimdall, reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` and `gnome-shell`, accidentally removing `coreutils` (and I've now learned about "Yes, do as I say!" verification message in apt-get, which you should never ignore  ). I went on mounting the system on a live usb as told in [this article](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery) (mainly the Update Failure part). I've reinstalled `coreutils`, `bsdmainutils`, `network-manager`, as well as `ubuntu-desktop` (again, though didn't seem to make much difference) and `gnome-shell`. And viola - here i am, typing on a new account, which my home folder still in /home and files all intact, untouched. Small copy of `.mozilla` and `.muttrc` files made me feel at home again on this new account. Next step will be just to change ownership of my old folder with `sudo chown -hR newAccount.newUsergroup /home/myOldFolder` and clean up the mess.

**In summary**

The whole thing has been just a combination of accidents, which resulted in me panicking. From a more positive outlook, I've learned a few good lessons for future.

Comment: Asking for suggestions in an answer isn't likely to obtain results. If you have another question, http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ElderGeek Thanks. My primary question was figuring out why the system wouldn't show any users and kerberos thing wouldn't let me change password. I wasn't exactly expecting an answer/suggestion here, as I know it's not related

Comment: I guess I was confused by "I'd appreciate any suggestions on closing the port or removing the kerberos-adm in some way; otherwise, if it works and is safe - good enough for me." Feel free to edit that part out or I can do it for you.

Comment: @ElderGeek Already did. Is it prohibited to include such statements in posts at all ?

Comment: Serg, to answer above question: No it's not, you will just have very little feed-back as it's an answer, not a question. Secondly: Well done! Congrats (and an upvote)  I would *immediately* make a system back-up and when the next LTS version comes out, re-install and *not* upgrade...

Comment: @Serg for future reference questions and answers regarding the usage of the site can be found here: http://meta.askubuntu.com I personally have found it very useful.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a boot CD, and either chroot & change password - make sure you `mount --bind` the CD $PATH directories though, not use any potentially bad executables - or else just add yourself as a new user, edit the numeric ID's, & copy the current /etc/passwd* to your drive - keeping a copy of the old ones - & re-try; if that doesn't fix it you could download chkrootkit & try that.

I would be less happy about using a USB stick for this purpose.

If it has been hacked, though, there could be any number of hidden things & I'd retrieve my data & wipe the laptop - probably with a `cat /dev/random >/dev/sda` on the way.

Comment: No need for a livecd; if you can't `sudo` then just boot into rescue mode.